# aspx page layout fails in IE9

Tags: asp.net, css, internet-explorer-9

I am trying to fix a problem which I'm not really sure how it is supposed to be fixed.(I've looked at a few things and tried them but to no success).
I have an aspx page that will serve as a bar. It is suppose to look like this(in chrome):
[image]

but when I run this in IE9, I get this:
[image]

In IE9 the bar gets split up in to two, and the "Description" label and textbox/button are all pushed to the one side.

This is my css(I validated it and no errors):

```
<style type="text/css">
    .mainContentHolder
    {
        margin: 0;
        background-color: #f3f3f3;
        border: solid 1px #a1a1a1; 
        min-width:890px;
        width:920px;
        height:50px;
    }
    .mainContentHolder h3
    {
        font-size:13px;
        font-style: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        line-height: 20px;
        margin-right: 1%;
    }
    .mainContentHolder label
    {
        font-size: 11px;
        font-style: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        line-height: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        margin-right: 1%;
    }
    .mainContentHolder input
    {
        width:70px;
    }
    .ui-dialog
    {
        font-size:12px;
    }
    .ui-widget-header
    {
        background: #8D122B;
    }
    .ui-datepicker
    {
        font-size:12px;
    }
    #quickNoteHeader
    {
       color: Green; 
    }
</style>
```

Comment: post HTML also or create a fiddle jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mrbiggels/UFxeC/

Comment: I found the problem. Apparently IE took my Textbox, the label "Description" and the button, and put it inside a div and made it float right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet Explorer 10 fixes this problem